# Xpath to get any tag containing subtext except <script>

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying to write an Xpath which finds all tags with text containing "substring". But I want to exclude `<script>` tags.

I tried to iterate over all elements, split xpath by slash and check last item. This should work but I want to make it more clear.

```
//*[contains(text(),"substring")]
```

Do you know how to exclude `<script> tags?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `//*[not(self::script) and contains(text(),"substring")]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
'//*[contains(., "substring") and not(name()="script")]'
```